# Activiti JNDI Datasource Configuration

Tags: spring, jndi, activiti

I am installing Activiti 5.17.0's Activiti Explorer and would like to use a JNDI-based datasource configuration to connect to an Oracle DB. The documentation I found here: http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#jndiDatasourceConfig is very explicit about making this change but unfortunately the docs seems to be obsolete.

In particular, I found no `activiti-standalone-context.xml` and no `activiti-context.xml` at the mentioned places. I assume it got changed to `activiti-custom-context.xml`, but the whole content of this Spring configuration is commented out (which makes me wonder where the actual Spring config might come from).

I tried to configure the datasource in this file anyway using this approach:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource"
           jndi-name="jdbc/activiti-ds"
           expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource" />
```

and this approach as well:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
           <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
           <property name="jndiName"><value>jdbc/activiti-ds</value></property>
</bean>
```

but both my attempts ended up in the same `ClassCastException`, claiming that the generated Proxy class is not an instance of `javax.sql.DataSource`:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$69ba43af cannot be cast to javax.sql.DataSource
    at org.activiti.explorer.conf.ActivitiEngineConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5db7207e.dataSource(<generated>)
    at org.activiti.explorer.conf.ActivitiEngineConfiguration.processEngineConfiguration(ActivitiEngineConfiguration.java:91)
```

Any hints how to accomplish to this task? Maybe a pointer to an up-to-date documentation?

Comment: i have same problem and very googling but not useful. i want to change activiti explorer database and change db.properties. when i want to login i dont know username and password. please help me. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For further reference, I solved the problem by editing the Spring JavaConfig in ActivitiEngineConfiguration.java and replacing the dataSource bean creation there with the following code:

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    final JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
    dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
    DataSource dataSource = dsLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/activiti-ds");
    return dataSource;
}
```

After recompiling the module and deploying, it seems to work flawlessly.

Thanks a lot to Greg Harley above whose questions and commented helped to solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

The Activiti users guide includes updated instructions for how to configure a JDBC datasource here: http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#jndiDatasourceConfig

You will need to configure a datasource bean in the ActivitiEngineConfiguration class of your web application and update the following line of code to reference your new datasource:

processEngineConfiguration.setDataSource(dataSource());

If you want to continue to use the Spring XML configuration, you can still define your custom beans in the activiti-custom-context.xml.

Comment: A couple of points..

- you referenced the same docs as I did and I still think it's obsolete (refers to non-existent config files for example)

- I did have an idea how to configure a JNDI datasource and it seems to get picked up the problem is the ClassCastException which I shown above. Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: In particular, the spring xml configuration which the linked official documentation refers to has been removed between 5.16.3 and 5.16.4 according to their git repository.

Comment: It sounds like you are refering to the sample applications (Explorer and rest). These are simply meant as exemplars and not fully function or completed apps. You can still use the Spring XML rather than Spring Annotations in your application (like in version prior to 5.16.2).

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to deploy those, but I can't get rid of the ClassCastException I added to the original post..

Comment: Ok, so your class cast exception indicates you are retrieving your datasource using JNDI. Can you include your bean configuration in this thread so we can verify that. If indeed you are creating a JndiObjectFactory rather than a datasource, then you will need to call the getObject() method on the bean and cast it to a DataSource.

Comment: I added two configuration attempts to the original question (and also edited the original question on the muddy details).

Comment: Case solved.. see my answer about a working JavaConfig using JNDI.